# trying to add honeywell wifi thermostat to old furnace

Tags: hvac

I see there are lots of post asking about the "C" wire and wifi thermostats so I apologize in advance for another one. I'm trying to install a new Honeywell T5 thermostat for my not so mobile father in law. His furnace is quite old and doesn't have a control board just transformers, coils and a limit switch. I have 5 wires to the stat which currently are all being used. Red-Rh, Blue-Rc, Yellow -Y, Green-G and White-W. The attached crude schematic show were they all go. There is also a picture of the overall components. Everything is wire nutted together.I guess my question is do I need to add a "C" wire and where would I land it since there are two transformers?[image: New thermostat termination point][image][image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Let's see if one of our pros can give you a good answer. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Can you get us an *exact* Honeywell model number for the new T-stat?  Also, are there spare wires available in the existing thermostat cable?

Comment: Honeywell T5 smart thermostat RCHT8610WF. No extra wires only the 5 but not difficult to add more. Knock on wood!

Comment: I added a 2 conductor cable and got a hold of honeywell and was told, with not to much confidence to, to connect to the transformer that is connected to the compressor. Problem solved.